# Java: In stack frame when and how is the current constant pool reference value populated?

Tags: java

I am trying to understand how a java virtual method is invoked. Per my understanding the object reference variable points to the object in heap from which object specific variable values are accessed and the method definition is pointed by the constant pool reference of the stack frame. The invoking method populates the reference variable (as it was a local variable for it). How and when is the constant pool reference value for the invoked method populated?
Please forgive if my understanding is incorrect.
Adding link for clarity 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK0MN.jpg

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, but if it's a pool of constants, then they should never change and only need to be populated once, at the start of execution, no?

Comment: There is no 'constant pool reference of the stack frame', or 'constant pool reference value for the invoked method' either; the invoking method does not 'populate the reference variable', whatever that is; and the rest of the question doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I was referring to the below image depicting the jvm working   https://imgur.com/a/rv8fW9X    It shows that each stack frame has local variable, operand stack and current class constant pool reference. I have read that the first local variable for a virtual method will be the this reference variable pointing to the object in heap followed by the arguments and these are populated by the invoking method. I wanted to understand when and how the current class constant pool reference is populated.

Comment: @EJP   2.6.3. Dynamic Linking
Each frame (§2.6) contains a reference to the run-time constant pool (§2.5.5) for the type of the current method to support dynamic linking of the method code. I wanted some clarification as to how this reference variable to the run-time constant pool gets populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How and when is the constant pool reference value for the invoked method populated?

The relevant constant pool is the one of the class in which the `invokevirtual` instruction appears.  The pool and all its contents are part of the class file.  They are created by the Java compiler, when the class overall is created from its Java source code.

Bytecode instructions that reference elements of the constant pool, such as `invokevirtual`, do so by the element's index, which is encoded (again, by the compiler) into the byte code.  It follows, then, that although the target object of an `invokevirtual` method may vary over different executions of the same instruction, the constant pool reference never does.  This corresponds directly to the fact that object references are held in variables in the Java language, but method invocation expressions require the method to be named explicitly.

Inasmuch as a *virtual* method invocation is performed, however, the method reference is resolved against the target object, and therefore the actual method invoked may vary.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/xitwyt9 In above image when main method calls d.move it will create a stack frame and push the reference variable in the local variables array. The reference variable d points to the object in heap which just contains variables and its values. The code for move() method for class Dog will be in the class data in method area which is pointed out by the constant pool reference variable?? If that is not the case how exactly is the method reference resolved against the target object.

Comment: @cloud, An object's data on the heap contains at least one piece of information even more important than the object's state: it identifies the object's *class*.  In your example, the CP of the `TestDog` class contains a method descriptor that gives the name, return type, and parameter types of the `move()` method that class will try to invoke.  This is constructed by the compiler by examining the declared type of the variable (`Animal`).  At runtime, the VM compares that to the methods provided by the target object's actual class and superclasses, and chooses the correct one.

Comment: John, Thank You for taking the time to reply to my questions.
From Oracle "Structure of JVM" Section 2.6.3. "Dynamic Linking - Each frame (§2.6) contains a reference to the run-time constant pool (§2.5.5) for the type of the current method to support dynamic linking of the method code."
Also in the following image https://imgur.com/a/rv8fW9X we can see something called as "Current Class Constant Pool Reference" in the stack frame pointing to the current class CP. When and how is the value for "Current Class Constant Pool Reference" populated?

Comment: @cloud, the VM is responsible for setting up and tearing down stack frames.  It sets the appropriate constant-pool reference in each stack frame when it creates that frame, just prior to starting execution of the method's bytecode.  The constant-pool reference is then fixed for the lifetime of the frame.

Comment: john You mentioned above that the object's data on the heap identifies the object's class, I have read that apart from the object's state (variable values) it has a reference/pointer pointing to the CP of its class.
Also the stack frame has a reference to the current class CP. Is this not redundant? The stack frame has a reference to the current class CP and it has reference to the object in heap which also has a reference to the CP?

Comment: No, @cloud, it is not redundant.  The two CPs that are referenced are often different.  An object's data refers to the CP of that object's class.  The CP in a stack frame refers to the class of the object on which the method was invoked.  The latter is used to access and manipulate `this`, including implicitly.  The former are used in accessing and manipulating the various other objects accessible from the method.